# Are there thermodynamic reasons a super diamagnet cannot exist?

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity, ferromagnetism

We define a super diamagnet as a substance which not only expels any internal magnetic fields but actually produces a stronger internal magnetic field in the opposite direction of the external field, in response to the external field.

So this would be something which is repelled by magnetic fields MORE strongly than even a super conductor which is a perfect diamagnet.

I am curious if there is some thermodynamic reason (making a perpetual motion machine etc...) that such a bulk material cannot exist.

I don't believe we know of any such materials (though I may be wrong here).

Comment: I suspect it could violate the first law in the following way. The object itself will become a dipole and would constantly try to rotate to align its magnetic field with the external magnetic field. This will generate unlimited amounts of energy because the torque will alway be on because the magnetic fields will never align.

Comment: I like your example. Trying to play with it, it could be that the rate of rotation of the object is inversely proportional to the distance between the magnet and the object and directly proportional to the magnetic field strength. So (cursorily) you don’t get unbounded acceleration necessarily. It’s just as you use stronger magnets OR bring them closer you can get it to spin faster if it’s fixed about a rotation anxis and it should similarly decelerate in rotation as magnets are pulled away.

Comment: This would be similar to how a dc motor works with magnetic fields that always miss each other

Comment: right, but a motor gives you unbounded energy as it works, from whatever energy source that  powers the motor, right? In this case there is no motor or energy source.

Comment: By unbounded I mean as much as you want if you wait enough, linearly in time.

Comment: Wouldn’t the strength of magnet and distance of magnet to our hypothetical superdiamagnet serves as an indicator of potential energy? The closer the magnet is, the more potential has been spent and thus our hypothetical superdiamagnet rotates faster, when we pull away the magnet said object then rotates slower. If we try to extract work out of the rotation rate with the magnet at a fixed distance then we can only extract as much energy as the rotational kinetic energy of the rotation of the superdiamagnet at said distance.

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magpot.html